Can't deploy application or retrieve existing applications in WasmCloud
I am trying to deploy a new application in the wasmcloud using the following command
wash app deploy wadm.yaml

It gives the following error,
Error making model request: no responders: no responders

The same error appears when I try to list down the existing application.
wash app list
Error making model request: no responders: no responders

What can be the reason for this issue

You need to be connected to a running wasmCloud lattice to deploy an application.
In a development environment, you can get a lattice up and running simply by running wash up.
